# Introjs with a single page application

Tags: javascript, jquery, intro.js

I have a single page application that I need to add a walkthrough on I'm using http://usablica.github.io/intro.js/.
My application has multiple wizard style pages they navigate through, so for each page (in the single page app) the walkthrough needs to start from the first step within that container.

This is how it is structured:

```
<fieldset id="page1">
    <input data-step="1" data-intro="instructions" />
    <input data-step="2" data-intro="instructions" />
    <button>Go to step 2</button>
</fieldset>
<fieldset id="page2">
    <input data-step="1" data-intro="instructions" />
    <input data-step="2" data-intro="instructions" />
    <button>Go to step 3</button>
</fieldset>
```

So when the user clicks 'Go to step 2' it needs to reset the intro and void the steps from the previous page (page 1) and start from step 1 on page 2.

Edit: If I can run it under a call back from my buttons that take you to the next step could I just have it look for the data-step's under a specific div for example the unique id of the active step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just modified this line: `var allIntroSteps = targetElm.querySelectorAll('.active *[data-intro]');`
With '.active' and added a call back to each step.